# Syntax of SoapAction in spring-ws config

Tags: soap, spring-ws

I'm having some problems regarding the SoapActionEndpointMapping and are wondering if it could be related to the format of the property. The [API](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/server/endpoint/mapping/SoapActionEndpointMapping.html) says that the mapping is

> SOAP_ACTION=ENDPOINT_BEAN_NAME

with the example

> http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws/samples/airline/GetFlights=getFlightsEndpoint

Am I correct assuming that "*http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws/samples/airline/*" is the namespace and "*GetFligths*" is the soapAction?

Answer (score 0):

No, SOAP actions are just URI strings, so you need to populate the handler mapping with a propertyset of URI keys to endpoint beans/names.